# Stopping MySQL query after the first row

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

I have a piece of MySQL code that searches through a quite lengthy mysql database. When done multiple times, it takes a long time, although the only thing I need from the code is to check the existence of at least one entry. Is it possible to instruct the mysql code to stop searching after finding one row? Thanks.

Comment: Add `LIMIT 1` to the query.

Comment: Whats wrong with `LIMIT 1` ?

Comment: Doesn't make the search any shorter.

Answer (score 4):

Try `LIMIT 1` at the end of your query.

Comment: That doesn't make the search shorter by any means, actually it sometimes makes it longer. Limit 1 just makes the code return 1 row instead of only searching for one.

Comment: The whole purpose of LIMIT is to prevent unneeded resource fetching. It's the same as WHERE and would never just chunk out the whole table to just fetch one row. That's a naive assumption.

Comment: Unfortunately the timer on PHPMyAdmin disagrees with you. LIMIT does not improve the time it takes to fetch the result at all.

Comment: The [mysql reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/limit-optimization.html) says "As soon as MySQL has sent the required number of rows to the client, it aborts the query"

Comment: Well no, it still needs to find the row - it just doesn't need to find _all the rows_.

Comment: I just checked again, without LIMIT 1, my query returns 33000 rows and with LIMIT 1, obviously 1 but unfortunately both take the same time (around 1.2 seconds)

Comment: Unless, somehow everything I am searching for is clumped at the very end of the table or something and it takes relatively the same time to reach the first entry compared to every entry.

Comment: You shouldn't test MySQL performance based on the phpMyAdmin tool. The reason of the same time in both cases is most likely just 95% of the time consumed is by the PHP code of phpMyAdmin, whereas the last 5% by the MySQL, thus seeing no difference. Try MySQL Workbench or the Commandline Tools to really test what the query's execution times are :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to search for just one thing then there must be some primary key associated with it. so in the query you can include somethere in where clause which will bring in only one result. something like this

```
    select * from students where id='123'
```

As primary keys are the unique key so there won't be any duplication and only one search will be done.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tablename LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0
```

- LIMIT will set the max items you want back
- OFFSET let's you state the starting point to start your query

Combining LIMIT and OFFSET gives you very precise control of fetching tons of database rows over multiple sessions.

Or use the easier 2-parameter LIMIT function (same as LIMIT, OFFSET):

```
SELECT * FROM tablename LIMIT 1, 0
```